# Object reference not set to an object: But where though

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, game-physics

I'm following a tutorial to create some jelly effects to a slime platformer character, the script is divided in two parts that I called "JellyBro" that makes the vertex jiggle and "jellyfier" that makes my Player bounce. The script doesn't have any typos and it should be working except for the Null Reference Exception that when I click brings me to a random part of my script...

I'm really new to scripts and stuff so I have no idea what it could be and other similar questions in the forums didn't really help

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
public class jellyfier : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float bounceSpeed;
    public float fallForce;
    public float stiffness;

    private MeshFilter meshFilter;
    private Mesh mesh;

    Jelly[] jellyVertices;
    Vector3[] currentMeshVertices;

    private void Start()
     {
         meshFilter = GetComponent<MeshFilter>();
         mesh = meshFilter.mesh;

         GetVertices();
     }

   private void GetVertices()
         {
             jellyVertices = new JellyBro[mesh.vertices.Length];
             currentMeshVertices = new Vector3[mesh.vertices.Length];
             for (int i = 0; i < mesh.vertices.Length ; i++)
             {
                 jellyVertices[i] = new JellyBro(i,mesh.vertices[i], mesh.vertices[i], Vector3.zero);
                 currentMeshVertices[i] = mesh.vertices[i];
             }
         }


    private void Update()
        {
            UpdateVertices();
        }

    private void UpdateVertices()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < jellyVertices.Length; i++)
            {
                jellyVertices[i].UpdateVelocity(bounceSpeed);
                jellyVertices[i].Settle(stiffness);

                jellyVertices[i].currentVertexPosition += jellyVertices[i].currentVelocity * Time.deltaTime;
                currentMeshVertices[i] = jellyVertices[i].currentVertexPosition;

            }

            mesh.vertices = currentMeshVertices;
            mesh.RecalculateBounds();
            mesh.RecalculateNormals();
            mesh.RecalculateTangents();

        }  
    public void OnCollisionEnter(Collision other)
    {
        ContactPoint[] CollisionPoints = other.contacts;
        for (int i = 0; i < CollisionPoints.Length; i++)
        {

            Vector3 inputPoint = CollisionPoints[i].point + (CollisionPoints[i].point * .1f);
            ApplyPressureToPoint(inputPoint, fallForce);
        }
    }
    public void ApplyPressureToPoint(Vector3 _point, float _pressure)
    {

        for (int i = 0; i < jellyVertices.Length; i++)
        {
            jellyVertices[i].ApplyPressureToVertex(transform, _point, _pressure);
        }
    }
}
```

So yeah I'm making this game for my portfolio so I really want it to be simple but well done and this shoot is stressing me out ha ha

Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: Please tell us where you are getting the error. Have you tried debugging your code

Comment: Well that's the thing, the error only comes when I try to play the game and it gives me the object reference error and it takes me to a different line every time but it doesn't say what character of the line !    Edit: I tried replacing "mesh" by the mesh's name but it creates errors so I guess that's not it